# How to print a JSON-structure from User models hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5 app and in this app I got a User model. Each user can have exactly one manager (using the attribute manager_id).

I want to print a JSON-structure (using Rabl) that shows how the User models are related. Meaning I want to print out how is manager to each user.

```
User 1 (manager_id is null)
|
User 2 (manager_id is 1)
User 3 (manager_id is 1)
|
User 4 (manager_id is 3)
```

This is what I want the UI to look like (this is already working I just need the JSON-structure to support it).

[image]

*These is how the finished structure must look like.*

```
datasource = 
        'name': 'Peter Fettingview'
        'title': 'CEO'
        'children': [
          {
            'name': 'Mike Palmer'
            'title': 'CIO'
          }
          {
            'name': 'Maria Persson'
            'title': 'CTO'
            'children': [
              {
                'name': 'James Hatton'
                'title': 'Customer success'
              }
              {
                'name': 'Lars Andersson'
                'title': 'Customer success'
              }
            ]
          }
          {
            'name': 'Jan Roslund'
            'title': 'Economy'
          }
          {
            'name': 'Annika Holm'
            'title': 'Sales'
          }
        ]
```

This is what I got right now

```
attributes :id, :fullname

node :children do |n|
   n.children.map { |c| partial("admin/users/index", :object => c)  }
end
```

*This is the output*

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "fullname": "Peter Fettingview",
    "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "fullname": "Richard Pooler"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fullname": "Mike Palmer"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "fullname": "Richard Pooler",
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "fullname": "Mike Palmer"
    }]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "fullname": "Mike Palmer",
    "children": []
}
```

]

How can I print out such a JSON-tree using the User models?

Comment: A suggestion would be to use Depth first search using recursion

Comment: How would that look like? My code only get my first level and to many nodes (see updated answer).

Comment: Using recursion and depth first traversal, you can get the results exactly as you require. it will not stop at the first level.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to use tree data structures (i.e. self-referential models) before.  I would consider using the [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).  It allows you to do things like enumerate descendants and paths bath to the root, making traversing your data structure significantly easier.